# How do I retrirve the transform value of a translate attribute when using getAttribute?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, transform, getattribute

How do I retrieve the transform value of a translate attribute when using getAttribute?

If I use setAttribute so create a transform on an object such as in the code below,

```
document.getElementById("Dots").setAttribute('transform','translateY(100)');
```

how do I later retrieve only the translate values using `.getAttribute('transform');`

Using `getAttribute` only retrieves the last transformation.  I want specifically only the value of the `translateY()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/4v7Yn/3/

Any ideas how I might go about accomplishing this?
Thanks,
--christopher

Comment: you `Dots` transform attribute is set to `skewX(60)`. What would be your expectation after setting the `transform` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement override the first one so you never get the `translateY` value.

See [**UPDATED DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/4v7Yn/4/)

```
document.getElementById("Dots").setAttribute('transform','translateY(100) skewX(60)');
alert(document.getElementById("Dots").getAttribute('transform').split(' ',1));
```

You can then use `split()` to get the specific value you want.

Comment: I specifically wanted the y translate value and found that I could get all transform values from the getCTM. `document.getElementById("Dots").getCTM().f;` F is the Y translate value and F/A gives the actual Y value of the translation.  It turns out I did not need to use the `.split`.